# Как предоставить общий доступ к данным сервера другим компьютерам сети?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, анализ-данных

Я хочу создать удобную инфраструктуру для студентов. В нашем классе есть один сервер сервером и дюжиной компьютеров для студентов. Сервер содержит данные для анализа. Данные хранятся в PostgreSQL (изначально это набор больших файлов json). Я хочу предоставить студентам доступ только для чтения к данным на сервере прямо из их ноутбуков Jupyter. Это означает, что я хочу, чтобы учащиеся могли загружать данные в `pandas.DataFrame` на своих локальных ПК из базы данных на сервере.

Как сделать это наиболее эффективным и простым способом?

Моя текущая идея состоит в том, чтобы создать пользователя в Postgres с разрешением только для чтения и разрешить учащимся [подключаться и запускать sql удаленно](https://gist.github.com/kunanit/eb0723eef653788395bb41c661c1fa86).

Comment: Можете уточнить суть вопроса? Вы не знаете как создать “read only user” в PostgreSQL?

Comment: @MaxU Мне кажется, что выбранный подход довольно сложный. Хочется, как можно сделать доступ к данным для студентов как можно проще. Вопрос в том, как организовать доступ к данным на сервере из Jupyter тетрадок студентов.

Comment: Поскольку база довольно объемная, то есть во время анализа все равно надо через SQL обращаться к данным, то появилась идея подсоединяться к удаленной базе. Есть ли другие варианты? Если нет, как сделать этот наиболее просто? (Может что–то вынести в отдельную микро библиотеку и тд?)

Comment: По-моему, нормальный подход. Можно наверное написать миникласс, который будет читать конфигурационный файл  с “connection details” и возвращать Engine object. А можно оставить как есть ;)

Comment: Создание connection string можно упростить если ключи словаря будут совпадать со значениями в строке (сейчас они в разных регистрах). Тогда можно было бы сделать так: conn_str = “...”.format(__**db__)